# token generation fails for user added to OpenLDAP directly

Tags: curl, wso2, token, openldap

We are using WSO2 API Manager Version 1.8.0

in the user-mgmt.xml we have configured JDBCUserStoreManager and ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.

We create users programatically into the OpenLDAP.

I see the programmatic-ally created users in wso2/carbon under users and roles.

If i try to generate the auth token for the new users it fails with the message

```
"{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Provided Authorization Grant is invalid."}"
```

CURL command

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=testuser@gogle.com&password=testpwd" -H "Authorization: Basic aGtPOUR6Um5WRENDeUU3YTYyVGlkQ3RyaklRYTpuOTBoQzhvS01KZnR5UDdjMWo1MFlCOV9zS2Nh, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" http:/IP:8280/token
```

Once the user is accessed from the http://sss/carbon the token generation goes fine.

When i turned on the logging TRACE i observed that if the user is fetched from userCache it works other wise it looks in the default  Using UserDNPatterns

```
uid={0},ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager
```

Not sure why WSO2 is lookat OU which is not specificed